# Incompatible type when trying to store an object in a variable of the very type

Tags: java

I do not understand why I can return an object implementing an interface but the compiler complains when trying to store this object in a variable of that very type.

Simple interface:

```
public interface ITest {

}
```

Now a simple class implementing the interface:

```
public class Test implements ITest {

}
```

Okay, so my understanding is: A `Test` *is an* `ITest`

Now the problem:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void parameterTest(ITest test) {

    }

    public static ITest returnValueTest() {
        return new Test(); // no compiler error here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();

        Tester.parameterTest(test);

        test = Tester.returnValueTest(); // compiler complains here
    }
}
```

The variable `test` is from type `Test` and therefore `ITest`. I can pass it to `Tester.parameterTest(ITest test)` without complains.

But trying to retrieve the value from `Tester.returnValueTest()` and to put it into the variable `test` fails with

`Incompatible types: ITest cannot be converted to Test`

although the method returns a `Test` object which the compiler does not complain about.

Why so? **Why can I return a `Test` object and be conform with the method’s return type `ITest` but cannot put this returned object into a variable of type `Test`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning a `Test` object, you are returning an `ITest` instance.

All `Test` objects implement `ITest` but not all `ITest` instances have to be `Test` objects.

Comment: Now I get it! My Idea was “the smaller will fit into the larger” but that’s the wrong way of thinking—`ITest` doesn’t satisfy the specification of `Test` and _that_ is the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To be thorough about this: My misunderstanding was, that I thought inheritance of objects is a matter of “the smaller fits into the larger”—but that is the wrong way of thinking.

Objects are about *interfaces*. Say we have a class `Lifeform` which can `grow()` and say we have a class `Dog` which is a `Lifeform` which can `bark()`. Returning a `Lifeform` “fits into” `Dog` somehow but not in every case fullfills the specification of `Dog` because not every `Lifeform` can `bark()`. Since the meaning of “type of a variable” is nothing else than “rest assured the object contained implements the interface specified by that very type” putting a `Lifeform` not being a `Dog` into a variable of type `Dog` would violate this assurance.

So in this case—if a method returns a `Lifeform` by signature, you cannot put this into a variable of type `Dog` because it is not neccessarily a `Dog` able to `bark()`. You can reassure the compiler, that the object returned is a `Dog` by casting, then it won’t complain. In other words, by casting you tell the compiler he can “rest assured the the `Lifeform` returned is a `Dog` which can `bark()`”.

---

So in my special case I can return a `Test` because it implements the interface `ITest` and everybody can be sure, the object returned will follow the specifications of `ITest` and hence the compiler does not complain. But the attempt to store this object in a variable of type `Test` fails unless the compiler is assured that the object indeed implements the interface provided by `Test`. So we have to cast it and all is rainbow and unicorns.

```
Test test = (Test) Tester.returnValueTest();
```

But we should be careful with this for it is a bit more error prone than just using variables of the correct type.